# Making python run a file in command line, input something, wait and then input something again

Tags: python, command-line, automation

In python, I wanted to do the following:
I have a command-line program that requires user to enter input step by step & wait in between to get the result. Now, I want to automate this process using python.

The process will be something like:

- run myProgram.exe in commandline
- enter command 1
- wait for command 1 to run & finish (takes ~5 minutes)
- enter command 2
  ...

is there a way to simulate this process in python? I knew that we can run a program & pass in command line parameters using os.open() or subprocess. But those are a one-off thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module and [`Popen.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to send data to the process stdin

EDIT:

You are right, he should use `stdin.write` to send data, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import time

print 'Launching new process...'
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'so1.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print 'Sending "something"...'
p.stdin.write('something\n')

print 'Waiting 30s...'
time.sleep(30)

print 'Sending "done"...'
p.stdin.write('done\n')

p.communicate()
print '=o='
```

Comment: Popen.communicate blocks until the process terminates, so the "enter command 2" part won't be possible.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix, or with cygwin python on Windows, the [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) module can automate interactive programs.

See the [examples here](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Overview). You'll want to pass a longer-than-default `timeout` argument to `expect()` for the part that takes five minutes.